# JQuery - how i can get variable of “file.JS”

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array called VLIST in a  file.js (an array of DOM Object)
need to rescue this matrix in a file. html
how can I do this?

I've tryed and i cannot use methods

*botoes.js:*

```
vList = [];
function getVList(vList){
    vList = vList;
    return vList;
};
```

*index.html:*

```
 function setVList() {
 return getVList(vList);
 }

xzz = getVList();

console.log(xzz);
```

**console.log:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getVList is not defined
```

I tried to follow this post, but i was unable:
[Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file)

Anyone know how to do?

Since now, thank you all.

Comment: Seems like `getVList()` is expecting some kind of input so `xzz = getVList();` would be invalid.

Comment: `getVList` is an identity function??? And `setVList` doesn't even take an argument???

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Even though it's probably not a useful way to call the function, it's perfectly valid. Assuming the function is really defined.

Comment: If it shows up as undefined, the relevant part of your code you would have to show us is the inclusion of the `botoes.js` script into your html file, together with the inline script tag that uses it.

Comment: I know my way is wrong, I wonder if you know how to do it right or assist in my solution. thanks to all.

Comment: @user2403131: But you haven't shown that part which you have done wrong? Please post your *whole* code.

Comment: @Bergi botoes.js is included in the html and this script is set in a <script>

Comment: @Bergi My whole code is too complex and giants, the only thing I want here is to pick a variable (in this case an array) of a file, and use in other

Comment: Either the `getVList` function is not defined in global scope, or you didn't include the file correctly. As long as you don't show me how you did that, nobody will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31142/discussion-between-user2403131-and-bergi)

Comment: @user2403131 If you could please post the code in your `<head></head>` tags this would be a little easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

no need for all that functions :)

botoes.js

```
var vList=['bla','blabla'];
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>vlist</title>
<script src="botoes.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(vList);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```