# Executing separate .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn how different `.js` files can  be included in a `HTML` file, so that my code becomes more modular. I am following this page [Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file). I am confused at one point, that if I include files like this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="a.js"> 
<script language="javascript" src="b.js">
```

If `a.js` contains:

```
function alertOne() {
   alert("one");
}
```

and `b.js` contains:

```
function alertTwo() {
   alert("two");
}
```

then do I need to separately call the functions in HTML file or just including the files like `<script language="javascript" src="b.js">` this, would execute `alertTwo()` function?

Comment: A function is executed only when you call it.

Comment: Including a Javascript file is essentially the same as just including the Javascript straight into the HTML, the function will **not** auto execute once included.

Comment: By the way. Did you try it by yourself? This is quite easy to test, IMO.

Comment: Yes, I tried it myself and I couldn't understand the point, see my comment in Anthony's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript files are just declaring the functions. If you want them to actually execute then yes, you'd need to call them at some point. Whether that's inside another .js file, inside a `<script>` tag in your HTML page, or as part of an event handler on an element, is up to you and depends on what exactly you want.

Comment: Then what is the point of including the files like `<script language="javascript" src="b.js">` ? I could have simply called the functions in different `.js` files or `HTML` file as necessary, right?

Comment: @user227666 Separate .js files makes it easier to re-use and maintain the code. Let's say you wanted those functions in *all* of your pages; if you just put the functions inside `<script>` tags in each of the .html files then you'd have to update them all when you wanted to make a change. It also introduces a separation of concerns; your HTML files handle content, CSS handles styling, and JS handles functionality, rather than having them all mashed together in a tangled mess.

Comment: You didn't get my point. Suppose, I have only 1 HTML file and       2 `.js` files like `a.js` and `b.js` like above. So, if I had to call the functions separately for execution then is there any point of `<script language="javascript" src="b.js">` and `<script language="javascript" src="a.js">` lines?

Comment: @user227666 Yes, those files declare the functions. You can't call/execute a function if it hasn't been declared first, you'll get an error. You could move the contents of those files into the HTML page instead, but you'd still have to execute the function separately and you'd also be moving into what I discussed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
function alertTwo() {
   alert("two");
}
```

*declares* a function that can be called later

The code:

```
function alertTwo() {
   alert("two");
}
alertTwo();
```

declares a function, and then immediately calls it.

The code:

```
(function alertTwo() {
   alert("two");
})();
```

declares a function that immediately calls itself.

It doesn't matter if your code is directly in the HTML file, or included via `script` tag. Nothing is "executed" or done special via `script` tag. It's effectively like saying "paste the stuff from that file here."

Comment: Then what is the point of including the files like `<script language="javascript" src="b.js">` ? I could have simply called the functions in different `.js` files or `HTML` file as necessary, right?

Comment: There are three major reasons to include script files: one, to keep your HTML page from being 34,124 lines long if you have a lot of javascript. Two, say page A, B, and D need the functionality of __z.js__ but pages C, E, F, G, H and K do not. Why include the file and make another HTTP request for the javascript if it's not needed? Thirdly, if your javascript is copied into 20 different HTML files, and ti changes, you update 20 files... if it's included from a single `.js` file, you update once.

Answer (score 0):

The function `alertOne()` in `a.js` can be called from `b.js` if both `a.js` and `b.js` are included in your HTML.