# How to call function from another js file; how to pass session variables to another js file

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

I'm a beginner in Javascript and learning how to create websites. I'm trying to add a google+ sign in feature into my web app but couldn't pass session information through javascript. I have 2 js files - login.js and profile.js. When a user logs in, login.js will run, and load a function from profile.js. I included both scripts in the index.html file but still gets this error: **loadProfile is not defined**. Been stuck for days and really appreciate some guidance!

Here's my code

index.html

```
  {head}
    {script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"}{/script}
    {script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"}{/script}
  {/head}
  {body}
  {script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/profile.js"}{/script}
  {script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/login.js"}{/script}
  {input type="button" id="login" value="Login" onclick="login()" /}
  {input type="button" id="logout" class="hide" value="Logout" onclick="logout()" /}
  {script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/logout.js"}{/script}
  {/body}
```

login.js

```
function login() {
   var myParams = {
'clientid' : '699XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
'callback' : 'loginCallback', 
'approvalprompt':'force',
'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com /auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
 };
gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
}

function loginCallback(result) {
  if(result['status']['signed_in']) {
  alert("Login Success");
  var obj = gapi.auth.getToken();
  loadProfile();                // Calls loadProfile() from profile.js
  }
 }
```

profile.js

```
function loadProfile(){  
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
request.execute(loadProfileCallback());
  }  
function loadProfileCallback(obj) {
profile = obj;
email = obj['emails'].filter(function(v) {
    return v.type === 'account';
})[0].value; 
displayProfile(profile);
  }
>>> subsequently it's just some callback functions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write some inline Javascript in your HTML on before your file declarations like so:

```
<script>
    function loadProfile(){  
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
        request.execute(loadProfileCallback());
    } 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/profile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/login2.js"></script>
```

In this way, this function is available globally for all subsequent files to use. Refer to this answer: [Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file) that had the same problem that you had and has an excellent explanation as to the scope of the files and their usage.

Comment: I tried putting the function into index.html but it gives rise to another problem: Error: gapi.client.plus is undefined. It seems that I have to complete my login.js before I can call loadProfile(), so I can't put this inline with index.html.

Comment: Where is the gapi variable defined? As you have not linked it, I cannot see where the variable has been declared, have you correctly referenced the google api script?

Comment: The gapi is Google+ API, which I have included in index.html header. <head> <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
</head>
Then I call the initializing process with login.js and perform the authorization check for Google+ log in