# Calling a JavaScript function in another js file

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to call a function defined in a *first.js* file in *second.js* file. Both files are defined in an HTML file like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

I want to call `fn1()` defined in `first.js` in `second.js`. From my searches answers were if `first.js` is defined first it is possible, but from my tests I haven't found any way to do that.

Here is my code:

`second.js`

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
    fn1();
}
```

`first.js`

```
function fn1() {
    alert("external fn clicked");
}
```

Comment: So call it, there is nothing special as long as it is in global scope.

Comment: We are all doing this a thousand of times per day. If you can't, there must be a problem with your first.js: Check whether it is loaded at all into your browser, and if yes, whether there was a syntax error while parsing it (both can be seen in the developer's toolbar of your browser)

Comment: It should work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file

Comment: That should work.  Please edit your question to tell us what happens when you run this using the JavaScript console in Chrome or Firefox/Firebug.  (Um, and check that you spelled the function name correctly.)

Comment: please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: If it doesn't work, I guess you are doing something wrong. Given the information in your question, it's impossible want it is though.

Comment: Thanks for the answers , I checked the console , no errors. checked spelling, no errors

Comment: Should the actual code.

Comment: How are you checking, show us the function in `first.js`, and you calling it in `second.js`.

Comment: I modified it to get me more clarify results and the console throws error when calling fn1() : 'fn1() is not defined'. I edited the question to show a sample of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So it seems it works fine, I was just experimenting a file located on a wrong location with the same name and I just wasted 2 hours of my project! Sorry everyone and thanks for your kind answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file)

Comment: It should work.
Test it here: https://codepen.io/constagorgan/project/editor/ARakvM

Answer (score 251, accepted):

A function cannot be called unless it was defined in the same file or one loaded before the attempt to call it.

A function cannot be called unless it is in the same or greater scope then the one trying to call it.

You declare function `fn1` in first.js, and then in second you can just have `fn1();`

**1.js:**

```
function fn1 () {
    alert();
}
```

**2.js:**

```
fn1();
```

index.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
```

Comment: So what's the best way to manage all this in a production application?

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Gives an error that fn1() is not defined

Comment: This doesn't work for me as well. Is there any work around except using jquery getscript as its suggest a bad practice?

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer with 82 votes if it doesn't really work?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: If this is not working for you, chances are you defined the function within something else. For instance, I had my function within a `$(document).ready(function() {...})` block, and it did not work. I moved it and it worked like a charm.

Comment: It wont work if u have a .mjs file instead of .js file or you export function f1 . I was doing both of those

Comment: Maybe you import 2.js before 1.js. For the function in 1.js to be callable by another script, 1.js should have been imported in index.html first.

Comment: Works for me. Don't make the mistake I did: using nodejs import/export syntax:

 `
export function fn1 () {
    alert();
}
`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelZiluck! In my case I had it in $(document).ready. I just left it there but changed it to be: 
var SaveShippingAddress = function(){ ... }   and that worked.

Comment: @MichaelZiluck What if you need to define the function in `jQuery(document).ready(function(${...` else the function itself won't work?

Answer (score 57):

You could consider using the es6 import export syntax. In file 1;

```
export function f1() {...}
```

And then in file 2;

```
import { f1 } from "./file1.js";
f1();
```

Please  note that this only works if you're using `<script src="./file2.js" type="module">`

You will not need two script tags if you do it this way. You simply need the main script, and you can import all your other stuff there.

Comment: With Safari, I get `cross-origin script load denied by cross-origin resource sharing policy`

Comment: With older browsers you may not be able to use the es6 import syntax. You could use Babel if it makes it easier for you.

Comment: How to (export and) import the whole content of the `file1.js` ?

Answer (score 36):

1st JS:

```
function fn(){
   alert("Hello! Uncle Namaste...Chalo Kaaam ki Baat p Aate h...");
}
```

2nd JS:

```
$.getscript("url or name of 1st Js File",function(){
fn();
});
```

Comment: I think you mean `jQuery.getScript()`

Comment: @Pmpr, the dollar sign is a shorthand for `jQuery`.

Comment: why am I getting an error for the same in the typescript that fn is unknown?

Comment: Doesn't work. `Unexpected token` error

Comment: Obviously, this would work only if jQuery is already loaded in the page.

Answer (score 26):

You can make the function a global variable in `first.js`
and have a look at [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)  and do not put it in `document.ready` put it outside

you can use ajax too

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "url to script",
      dataType: "script",
      success: success
    });
```

same way you can use [jquery getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

Comment: Beginners never try doing anything like this. These are bad practices to be avoided. As long as both are referenced by the web page, yes.
You simply call the functions as if they are in the same JS file.

Comment: The only issue is, it doesn't include the header for some reason.

Comment: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 21):

**declare function in global scope with window**

first.js

```
window.fn1 = function fn1() {
    alert("external fn clicked");
}
```

second.js

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
   fn1();
}
```

include like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this recommended? What If I have 1000 functions.  What I'm trying to do is to have a single JavaScript file to hold all event listeners. But to make that work I would have to declare each function in global scope as you suggest. Wouldn't this slow things down?

Answer (score 11):

use "var" while creating a function, then you can access that from another file. make sure both files are well connected to your project and can access each other.

file_1.js

```
var firstLetterUppercase = function(str) {
   str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
      return letter.toUpperCase();
   });
   return str;
}
```

accessing this function/variable from file_2.js file

```
firstLetterUppercase("gobinda");
```

> output => Gobinda

Answer (score 7):

It should work like this:

**1.js**

```
function fn1() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "fn1 gets called";
}
```

**2.js**

```
function clickedTheButton() {
  fn1();
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="clickedTheButton()">Click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**output**

[image: Output. Button + Result]

Try this CodePen snippet: [link](https://codepen.io/constagorgan/project/editor/ARakvM) .

Answer (score 7):

Please note this only works if the

```
<script>
```

tags are in the body and NOT in the head.

So

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
</head>
```

=> unknown function fn1()

Fails and

```
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
</body>
```

works.

Comment: OH THAT'S WHY! your answer was really helpful as I couldn't figure out why, although my scripts were in correct order, the functions still were undefined. Why does this happen, though?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually coming very late, but I thought I should share,

in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
```

in 1.js

```
fn1 = function() {
    alert("external fn clicked");
}
```

in 2.js

```
fn1()
```

Comment: Please see the OP's comment under the question: "...I was just experimenting [with] a file located on a wrong location with the same name...".

Answer (score 3):

Use cache if your server allows it to improve speed.

```
var extern =(url)=> {           // load extern javascript
    let scr = $.extend({}, {
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true,
        url: url
    });
    return $.ajax(scr);
}
function ext(file, func) {
    extern(file).done(func);    // calls a function from an extern javascript file
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
ext('somefile.js',()=>              
    myFunc(args)
);
```

Optionally, make a prototype of it to have it more flexible. So that you don't have to define the file every time, if you call a function or if you want to fetch code from multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

### first.js

```
function first() { alert("first"); }
```

### Second.js

```
var imported = document.createElement("script");
imported.src = "other js/first.js";  //saved in "other js" folder
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(imported);


function second() { alert("Second");}
```

### index.html

```
 <HTML>
    <HEAD>
       <SCRIPT SRC="second.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
       <a href="javascript:second()">method in second js</a><br/>
       <a href="javascript:first()">method in firstjs ("included" by the first)</a>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

*better late than never*

```
(function (window) {const helper = { fetchApi: function () { return "oke"}
   if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(function () { return helper; });
   }
   else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = helper;
  }
  else {
    window.helper = helper;
  }
}(window))
```

index html
`<script src="helper.js"></script>`
`<script src="test.js"></script>`

in test.js file
`helper.fetchApi()`

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
        fn1();
    }
   // this should work, It calls when all js files loaded, No matter what position you have written
});
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

```
// module.js
export function hello() {
  return "Hello";
}

// main.js
import {hello} from 'module'; // or './module'
let val = hello(); // val is "Hello";
```

reference from https://hype.codes/how-include-js-file-another-js-file

Answer (score 1):

**My idea is let two JavaScript call function through DOM.**

The way to do it is simple ...
We just need to define hidden js_ipc html tag.
After the callee register click from the hidden js_ipc tag, then
The caller can dispatch the click event to trigger callee.
And the argument is save in the event that you want to pass.

When we need to use above way ?

Sometime, the two javascript code is very complicated to integrate and so many async code there. And different code use different framework but you still need to have a simple way to integrate them together.

So, in that case, it is not easy to do it.

In my project's implementation, I meet this case and it is very complicated to integrate. And finally I found out that we can let two javascript call each other through DOM.

I demonstrate this way in this git code. you can get it through this way. (Or read it from https://github.com/milochen0418/javascript-ipc-demo)

```
git clone https://github.com/milochen0418/javascript-ipc-demo
cd javascript-ipc-demo
git checkout 5f75d44530b4145ca2b06105c6aac28b764f066e
```

Anywhere, Here, I try to explain by the following simple case. I hope that this way can help you to integrate two different javascript code easier than before there is no any JavaScript library to support communication between two javascript file that made by different team.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="js_ipc" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="test_btn" class="btn">
        <a><p>click to test</p></a>
    </div>    
</body>
<script src="js/callee.js"></script>
<script src="js/caller.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the code
css/style.css

```
.btn {
    background-color:grey;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

js/caller.js

```
function caller_add_of_ipc(num1, num2) {
    var e = new Event("click");
    e.arguments = arguments;
    document.getElementById("js_ipc").dispatchEvent(e);
}
document.getElementById("test_btn").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log("click to invoke caller of IPC");
    caller_add_of_ipc(33, 22);      
});
```

js/callee.js

```
document.getElementById("js_ipc").addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    callee_add_of_ipc(e.arguments);
});    
function callee_add_of_ipc(arguments) {
    let num1 = arguments[0];
    let num2 = arguments[1];
    console.log("This is callee of IPC -- inner-communication process");
    console.log( "num1 + num2 = " + (num1 + num2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem. I have had defined functions inside jquery *document ready* function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function xyz()
   {
       //some code
   }
});
```

And this function *xyz()* I have called in another file. This doesn't working :) You have to defined function above *document ready*.

Comment: This is downvoted but is the same problem I had. My solution is to take the function out of the $(document).ready() function.

Answer (score -1):

#### TLDR: Load Global Function Files first, Then Load Event Handlers

Whenever you are accessing an element within a JS file or `<script>` block, it is essential to check to make sure that element exists, i.e., jQuery's `$(document).ready()` or plain JS's `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event)...`.

However, the accepted solution *does NOT work* in the event that you add an event listener for the DOMContentLoaded, which you can easily observe from the comments.

#### Procedure for Loading Global Function Files First

The solution is as follows:

- Separate the logic of your JS script files so that each file only contains event listeners or global, independent functions.
- Load the JS script files with the global, independent functions first.
- Load the JS script files with event listeners second.  Unlike the other previous files, make sure to wrap your code in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {...})`. or `document.Ready()`.