# Access a Function From Another File

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, scope

I have two file:

`html2canvas.js`

```
function html2canvas(){

}
```

`myid_print.js`

```
(function ($) {  
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        //I want to call html2canvas function here
        html2canvas();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I already included both files in my html but after running the code above, the console shows an error saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined
```

How will I call the function from inside my second file?

Comment: Check for the order in which you have included the files

Comment: Add the `html2canvas` before the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing your Client side code as :

```
<head>
....
    <script src="html2canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="myid_print.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
....
<head>
<body>
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function_from_myid_print();
    </script>
...
</body>
```

Inside which you can call html2canvas();

This will surely help you.

For more details refer links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809896/4763053 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25963012/4763053

Answer (score 0):

Try put your JS script at the bottom of your HTML page.