# how to create a js function and use it on another files

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thank you in advance.

I need to build a JS file that contains some useful functions and wich will be reused on my website.

**Content of File 1: utils.js**

```
function clearForm(form){
$(form).find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
$(form).find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
    .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}

function anotherFunction(){
//
}

function anotherFunction1(){
//
}
```

**and this is the file 2: control.js**

```
function postRecovery(email) {
var retorno;

$.ajax({
    url: "/auth/doRecuperarSenha/",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(email),
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function () {
        NProgress.start();
    },
    success: function (dados) {
       retorno = dados;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Erro");
    },
    complete: function () {
**this.clearForm(*email*);**
        NProgress.done();
    }
});
NProgress.remove();
}
```

But this does not work.

**Clarification**

> I've imported the **utils.js** file before the **control.js** file on my html structure
>
> My code worked when i put the script on the same file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file

Comment: I don't think you are calling your function correctly. Write a log statement in your function and check if it is even being called correctly.