# Javascript calling function on server in another Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have a server.js with the function

```
function isLogged(req) {
    var x = false;
     if(req.session.logged === 'Yes'){
       x = true;
     }
     else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

I want to call this function with the javascript for another page.
For example on the welcome.js page.

Comment: is server.js a server-side script ? is it executed by nodejs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25962958/4470542

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a javascript function in another js file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file)

Comment: Yes, it is executed by nodejs

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you are using node.js ,To check check if user is logged in or not use this funtion a a middleware in all your application routes.

```
app.get('/somelink',isLogged,function(){
    if(user is logged in){
        'serve the requested page'
    }else{
        'redirect to login page'
    }
});
```