# Aframe - call aframe function from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, triggers, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to turn positional tracking off, and I believe that this function in the aframe code is what I'm after:

checkHasPositionalTracking();

However, in my second js file (which is defined AFTER aframe.js), if I try to call that function, I receive this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: checkHasPositionalTracking is not defined

Comment: This question is not about A-Frame; it's a general JavaScript question which has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file

Comment: sorry, I should have been more specific since I tried that and it didn't work. I thought aframe might have something else going on that doesn't allow this to work the same way.

Comment: Have you tried calling the function with its A-Frame reference?
`AFRAME.utils.device.checkHasPositionalTracking ()`

Comment: ah! thank you. Yes that seems to resolve the error, though it seems like AFRAME.utils.device.checkHasPositionalTracking(false); is not enough to stop Aframe from using positional tracking. But that's a different question! 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084550/aframe-can-positional-tracking-be-turned-off)
Thank you and if you post that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it with full reference to the window.AFRAME browser global, so use `AFRAME.utils.device.checkHasPositionalTracking ()` in your code to access it.