# Aframe - can positional tracking be turned off?

Tags: tracking, aframe, panoramas, webvr

I'm combining panoramas with 3D geometry, so I need to turn positional tracking off for anyone using an Oculus or a Vive, otherwise it's pretty instantly nauseating. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: small update, I found this in the aframe js:
function checkHasPositionalTracking ()

so with my limited coding knowledge, I'm sure I could directly modify that to always return false, but I'd prefer to leave it alone if possible. Ideally, another script could affect that and override the VR device.

Comment: Tried checkHasPositionalTracking(false); and that doesn't seem to work.