# Does the function utils.device.checkHasPositionalTracking() still exist?

Tags: javascript, device, aframe, detection, webvr

I'm getting an error on desktop chrome that `utils.device.checkHasPositionalTracking() is "not a function".`

If it is obsolete, where can I find an updated list of `utils.device` methods for device detection?  The official documentation seems to be outdated and lists depreciated methods for device detection.  The browser doesn't seem to recognize this one in particular at all.

```
let mobile = AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile ();
//// isOculusGo and isGearVR have been replaced with isMobileVR
//let gearVR = AFRAME.utils.device.isGearVR();
//let oculusGo = AFRAME.utils.device.isOculusGo();
let mobileVR = AFRAME.utils.device.isMobileVR
//let tracking = AFRAME.utils.device.checkHasPositionalTracking(); //not working
let headset =AFRAME.utils.device.checkHeadsetConnected();

if(mobile){
  console.log("Viewer is mobile.");
}
if(mobileVR){
  console.log("Viewer is MobileVR.");
}
/*if(tracking){
  console.log("Viewer has positional tracking.");
}*/
if(headset){
  console.log("Headset Connected.");
}
```

The previous code results in "Viewer is MobileVR" even though I'm testing on a desktop computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aframe - call aframe function from another javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083888/aframe-call-aframe-function-from-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's gone, I couldn't find it in the source code of A-Frame either.

My pull request for the deletion in the documentation was approved just now:
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4255