# Function is defined in the same file but undefined in another file

Tags: javascript, jquery

In file_b.js I have the function

```
function date_of_birth(target, selector, days) { // Do something }
```

In file_a.js I try to call the function with `date_of_birth('a', 'b', 30)` but I get the error: **date_of_birth is not defined**

So I tried it with:

```
window.date_of_birth = function date_of_birth(target, selector, days) { // Do something }
```

When I call `window.date_of_birth('a', 'b', 30);`, I get the error: **window.date_of_birth is not a function**

When I call `console.log(window.date_of_birth);`, I get **undefined**.

In both files I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Why is my function not defined??

Comment: how do you include those files?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file

Comment: Simple solution, define the function in the global scope in `b` file, and, in `a` file, call the function inside of `$(document).ready`

Comment: use:
window.onload = function(){
 // defined ur function inside here
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in late 2020, you'd use modules to do this, either relying on the native support that's present in all modern major browsers, or bundlers like Webpack or Rollup.js that take code using module syntax and bundle it for older browsers.

With module syntax, in the simple case, you'd *export* the function you want to provide:

```
export function date_of_birth(/*...*/) {
    // ...
}
```

That's an *exported function declaration*, which creates a named export. Code in another module that wanted to use that function would *import* that function:

```
import { date_of_birth } from "./module-name.js";
```

There's a lot more to this topic, more [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) or in Chapter 13 of my book *JavaScript: The New Toys* (links in my profile if interested).

---

Old answer:

In your original code, it's undefined because it's not a global. When you define a function within another function, as I take it you've done, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function date_of_birth(target, selector, days) { // Do something }
});
```

...the function is **only** accessible within that `ready` callback, not globally.

When you changed it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.date_of_birth = function date_of_birth(target, selector, days) { // Do something };
});
```

that does indeed make it a global, so the error tells us that the `ready` callback for the other file (where you're *using* the function) runs before the `ready` callback in that file (where you're *defininig* the function).

How to fix it:

1. Pick a unique identifier for your app, say `MyApp`. (It doesn't have to be globally unique, it just has to A) Not be something defined in the browser environment, B) Not be something likely to be defined in the browser environment at some point in the future, and C) Not be something defined by any lib you use.) For instance, jQuery uses `jQuery`.
2. In your file where you define this function, do this:

   ```
    var MyApp = MyApp || {};
    MyApp.date_of_birth = function date_of_birth() { /*...*/ };
   ```

   Or if you have shared functions for class-wide data or something that you want to keep private, you could use a wrapper function:

   ```
    var MyApp = MyApp || {};
    (function() {
        function privateWorkerFunction() {
        }
        MyApp.date_of_birth = function date_of_birth() { /*...*/ };
        // ...
    })();
   ```
3. In your file where you use that, use it like this:

   ```
    MyApp.date_of_birth(/*...*/);
   ```
4. Ensure that the file defining the function is before the file using it, put both at the end of the HTML (just before the closing `</body>` tag), and get rid of the `ready` callbacks (there's no need; if the scripts are at the end of the document, things are ready enough).

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. It was even enough to remove the function from `ready()` and it also works without the unique identifier.

Comment: @RezaSaadati: Yes, but if you do that, you're creating a global for every function, and the global namespace is **really** crowded. Using a single identifier (`MyApp` in the example) helps you avoid conflicts.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you, I will use your code. Could you please tell me what `MyApp || {};` stands for?

Comment: @RezaSaadati: I really should have explained that. :-) `var MyApp` will declare the variable if it hasn't already been declared and give it the initial value `undefined`. If it's *already* been declared (for instance, in another of your files), `var MyApp` does nothing. The `= MyApp || {}` sets the variable either to the value it already has (if that value isn't "falsy") or to a freshly-created object (`{}`). So if you use this in each of your files, the *first* file will create the variable and assign an object to it, and all the others will use the object that's already there.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is soo useful!! In future I will always do it this way.

Comment: Could you explain #2 why you wrapped `MyApp.date_of_birth =` in an `anonymous self-invoking function`? Would it work the same without the wrapper? Also, in #3, could you show us how you would use `import`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `file_b.js` before `file_a.js` in your HTML page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file_b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file_a.js"></script>
```

so that when you call `date_of_birth('a', 'b', 30)` from `file_a.js` it is already rendered through `file_b.js`.

Answer (score 0):

when you declare function `function date_of_birth(target, selector, days) { // Do something }` you do not need to `$(document).ready(function(){ })`.

declare `date_of_birth` function outside of `$(document).ready` function and then try.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That was the solution.

Comment: @RezaSaadati don't forget to accept this solution..!