# how can i call function js in another file js ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**js1.js**

```
    app.controller('test1Controller', 
    function($scope,$http,$ngBootbox,$location,CRUDService,NotificationService,constants,ngWizard) {


    $scope.fun1 = function(){

        $http.get(context+"/back/demande/rest/test1").success(function(data, status) {   
            $scope.dto = data;
        });
    };

    });
```

**js2.js**

```
    app.controller('test2Controller', 
    function($scope,$http,$ngBootbox,$location,CRUDService,NotificationService,constants,ngWizard) {


    $scope.fun2 = function(){

        $http.get(context+"/back/demande/rest/test2").success(function(data, status) {   
            $scope.dto = data;
        });
    };

    });
```

How can I call fun1 => js1.js in js2.js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a javascript function in another js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file)

Comment: If the method should be shared, why not put it in a service that is injected into both controllers?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to move your function to angular.js `service` instance.
Then you need to inject this service to your controllers, like `NotificationService`.
Then you can call in different controllers.

```
app.service('myHttpService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.getData = function(context, endpoint) {
        return $http.get(context+"/back/demande/rest/" + endpoint);
    };
}]

// do not forget to use injector if you don't have ngAnnotate 
app.controller('test2Controller', function($scope, $http, $ngBootbox, $location, CRUDService, NotificationService, constants, ngWizard, myHttpService) {
    $scope.dto = null;

    $scope.fun2 = function(){
        myHttpService.getData(context, 'test1')
            .then(function(data, status) {   
                $scope.dto = data;
            });
    };

    });
```