# How to call function from one js file to another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend, es6-modules

I have a function defined inside  in HTML which is of module type.I need to call that function from another js file included in that same HTML file. When I call a function from a js file, it is referred to as reference error.

**This is what I have in my HTML file** :

```html
<script src="../src/viewer.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="../pravintest/player.js"></script>
```

In *viewer.js* file I have a code where I call a function *crossdatacheck(param)* which is in player.js.

This is my player.js file:

```js
 import * as THREE from './threejs/build/three.module.js';
        import { GUI } from './threejs/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js';
        import { OrbitControls } from './threejs/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        import { NRRDLoader } from './threejs/examples/jsm/loaders/NRRDLoader.js';
        import { VolumeRenderShader1 } from './threejs/examples/jsm/shaders/VolumeShader.js';
        import { WEBGL } from './threejs/examples/jsm/WebGL.js';


        var renderer,
            scene,
            camera,
            controls,
            material,
            volconfig,
            cmtextures;

         function crossdatacheck(data) {
        console.log(data);
         }
```

I want to call this function from the viewer.js file.

When I call a function from viewer.js there is an error ->  *reference error*: *crossdatacheck function is not defined in viewer.js*
Can anyone suggests to me how can I do this?

Comment: Import the `player.js` file before the `viewer.js` file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a javascript function in another js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file)

Comment: Are you using `type="module"`? You must `export` functions from a module.

Comment: @rishichawda, No it does not !!!!

Comment: The thread does have a working answer. This one precisely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58152287/11104618

Comment: I have one question, I can import function in viewer.js only if I make  <script type=" module" src="viewer.js"> while, that make every global variable and function of viewer.js that is called from other js file inaccessible without exporting? I am working on preexisting project so I cannot the whole project.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules have their own scope and top level `var` statements and `function` declarations do not create globals. (This is good, globals are problematic).

To deal with this:

1. `export` the variables you want to use outside the module
2. Change the `<script>` that loads *viewer.js* so it loads it as a module
3. Remove the `<script>` that loads *player.js*
4. Import the variables from *player.js* that you want to use with an `import` statement inside *viewer.js*

Comment: This is a pre-existing project, there are other files that calls the function in this file. If I change this to the module, other files also have to import what they are calling right?

Comment: I have a function setdataset() in viewer.js which i am using as a event handler in HTML element 
<select id='dataset' onchange='setDataset(this.value);' class='custom-select' style="max-width: 200px"></select>

This is throwing error that setData is not defined.

Comment: Same problem. It isn't a global. Bind event handlers with `addEventListener`, not HTML.