# Initialize js function on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a js file where there is a function with multiple parameters

```
function initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, CLONES_COUNT, doAutoPlay) {
. . .
}
```

And I want to use this function on different pages, but with slightly different parameters, let's say for one of the pages there will be

```
initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1)
```

The question is, how do I call this initialization function on the page itself?

The usual page for laravel, blade.php where at the end there is a section with scripts

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
@endsection
```

I tried like this

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);
   });
</script>
@endsection
```

I seem to be doing everything right, but I get errors

> jQuery.Deferred exception: initSlider is not defined ReferenceError: initSlider is not defined at HTMLDocument. (http://test.loc/blog/article_1:730:9)
> at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:30038)
> at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:30340) undefined

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initSlider is not defined at HTMLDocument. (article_1:730)
> at e (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
> at t (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)

Comment: Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962958/calling-a-javascript-function-in-another-js-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your function inside [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> The .ready() method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the
> page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate. This
> will often be a good time to perform tasks that are needed before the
> user views or interacts with the page, for example to add event
> handlers and initialize plugins.

Explanation: Scripts get loaded asynchronously, thus it is not guaranteed that your script file will be loaded before you call the function. Using `.ready()` you make sure the function is called once everything else is loaded.

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/js/slider.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);
   });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: get this `jQuery.Deferred exception: initSlider is not defined ReferenceError: initSlider is not defined`

Comment: does your slider.js define it? What does the debugger say?

Comment: it does not come to the slider.js file, if you write this `initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides, (slides.length < 2) ? 0 : 1, slides.length > 1);` in the file itself before the `initSlider` function, then everything will work

Comment: but I need to call from blade.php

Comment: I do not have initSlider defined on the page itself

Comment: is the initSlider defined at all? what happens if you call it from the console?