# How to use function declared in different JS file using jQuery getScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, include, getscript

I have two JS files. One is called common.js and it use $.getScript to include other file with my js code. Part of including looks like this:

```
jQuery.getScript(js_path + "table.js", function(){
  generateTable(chartData, dataTypes);
});
```

This file (common.js) also contains function compare(a, b).

Now, the second one (table.js) has declared different function which uses the compare function from the first file. Something like this:

```
function someName() {
  var a = 2, 
      b = 5;
  var test = compare(a, b);
  return test;
}
```

When I run the code it gives me:

Uncaught ReferenceError: compare is not defined

How can I use function from the first file.

Comment: here the example [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3809896/2749470)

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need to use the getScript rather than simply including both scripts?

Comment: @Luc I have to divide the code into separate files to make it more clear

Comment: @David Yea, but you can put multiple script-tags rather than fetching one with the other. Beside that point, you clearly have a circular dependency between the two files which makes it a bit tricky.

Comment: right, but there are dependencies between them so that's why I have to use it

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.getScript` first fetches the JS file from the server, then executes it. If you want to work with global functions (as it seems) you need to pay attention to the following:

- Your `compare` function must be declared before the `table.js` file is executed.
- The `compare` function must be declared on the global namespace of `table.js`.

Sorry but without more info this is all you can get.

If your main file, as something like:

```
(function() {

   function compare(){...}

}());
```

Then the `compare` function is not declared in the global namespace.

Comment: How can compare function can be declared after since table.js uses it?

Answer (score -1):

did you check the order of imports? The file with 'compare' method should be first. It should solve the problem.

Comment: this compare function is declared in the same file which uses getScript, but before getScript function is used

Answer (score -1):

What I would suggest is to skip getScript if it's just for separating the code.

```
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script src="table.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Where common functions go into common, your table stuff goes into table. This way you get the ordering right. This also clears out the circular dependency one might see a hint of if table depends on common that depends on table by extracting all but the 'common' parts into some form of 'app'.

Comment: this doesn't answer what the OP asked.