# call a javascript function from within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

I am coding a chat program but i am stuck in this part.

```
var Controller=function conversation() {
this.createMessageNode=function(msg,sender,time,mid){
    var newMessage;
    if(sender==sessionStorage.getItem('userid')){
        newMessage="<div class='message-sent' id='"+mid+"'>"+msg+"<span class='time'>"+time+"</span></div>";
    }else{
        newMessage="<div class='message-recv' id='"+mid+"'>"+msg+"<span class='time'>"+time+"</span></div>";
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastMessage',mid);
    $('.chat-messages').append(newMessage);
}

this.getMessages=function(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('lastMessage')==null){
        sessionStorage.setItem('lastMessage',0);
    }
    $.ajax({url:"getmessages.php",type:"POST",data:{last:sessionStorage.getItem('lastMessage'),cid:sessionStorage.getItem('conversationid')},success:function(result) {
        var messages=JSON.parse(result);
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            createMessageNode(messages[i].message,messages[i].sender,messages[i].time,messages[i].mid);
            var cont=document.getElementById('chat-messages');
            cont.scrollTop=cont.scrollHeight;
        };
    }});
}
```

}

now when i do this it shows an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createMessageNode is not defined
```

now in the for loop "this" variable is referring to the ajax object. how can i call the createMessageNode function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file)

Comment: try `this.createMessageNode(messages[i].message,messages[i].sender,messages[i].time,messages[i].mid);`

Comment: when i use this.create....it shows this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.createMessageNode is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `createMessageNode()` is a method of the `Controller` object instance, so you need to refer to the instance when calling it. Without refering to the instance, the JavaScript engine is looking for the function in the current scope, then each higher scope all the way up to the global scope.

Typically you would use the `this` keyword to reference the instance, but in your case, the jQuery ajax call has changed the `this` context, so you can't directly use `this`.

A possible solution is, before the ajax call, store the `this` context:

```
var that = this;
```

Now, in the ajax success function:

```
that.createMessageNode(messages[i].message,messages[i].sender,messages[i].time,messages[i].mid);
^^ refer to the instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are bound to the `this` object. If it is a global object (top most parent scope) then you can reference the functions within `this` by `this.yourfunction`

You must study SCOPE properly to understand

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: look what i get when i print `for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    console.log(this);
    this.createMessageNode(messages[i].message,messages[i].sender,messages[i].time,messages[i].mid);
    var cont=document.getElementById('chat-messages');
    cont.scrollTop=cont.scrollHeight;
   };` inside the for loop:`Object {url: "getmessages.php", type: "POST", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true…}`

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be better to write your code following better prototypical inheritance models, like so:

```
function Controller() {
    this.chatMessages = $('.chat-messages');
}

Controller.prototype.createMessageNode = function (msg, sender, time, mid) {
    var newMessage;
    if (sender == sessionStorage.getItem('userid')) {
        newMessage = "<div class='message-sent' id='" + mid + "'>" + msg + "<span class='time'>" + time + "</span></div>";
    } else {
        newMessage = "<div class='message-recv' id='" + mid + "'>" + msg + "<span class='time'>" + time + "</span></div>";
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastMessage', mid);
    this.chatMessages.append(newMessage);
};

Controller.prototype.getMessages = function () {
    var _this = this;

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('lastMessage') === null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('lastMessage', 0);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "getmessages.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            last: sessionStorage.getItem('lastMessage'),
            cid: sessionStorage.getItem('conversationid')
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var messages = JSON.parse(result);
            for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                _this.createMessageNode(messages[i].message, messages[i].sender, messages[i].time, messages[i].mid);
            }
            var cont = $('#chat-messages');
            cont.scrollTop(cont.scrollHeight);
        }
    });
};
```

This solves the issue of the context by creating a true class, for example:

```
var conversation = new Controller();
conversation.getMessages();
conversation.createMessageNode('Hello, World!', 'JimmyBoh', new Date(), 8268124);
```

Also, whenever you have nested functions, it can help to store the desired context in a local variable, such as `_this` or `that`, etc. Here is a more simple example:

```
function outer() {
    // Temporarily store your desired context.
    var _this = this;

    // Make any call that executes with a different context.
    $.ajax({
        url: "getmessages.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function inner(result) {
            _this.doSomething(result);
        }
    });
};
```

Lastly, there might be a time when you want to execute a method in a different context than the current. `.call()` and `.apply()` can be used to run a method with a specified context and arguments. For example:

```
function printThis() {
    console.log(this.toString());
    console.dir(arguments);
}

printThis.call('Hello, World!');
printThis.call('Call array:', [2, 4, 6, 8], 10);   // Keeps arguments as-is.
printThis.apply('Apply array:', [2, 4, 6, 8], 10); // Accepts an array of the arguments.


function Sum(startingValue) {
    this.value = startingValue || 0;
}

Sum.prototype.add = function (number) {
    this.value += number;
}

var realSum = new Sum(2);
var fakeSum = {
    value: 3
};

realSum.add(1);
Sum.prototype.add.call(fakeSum, 2);

console.log(fakeSum.value); // Prints '5'
console.log(realSum.value); // Prints '3'
```