# Javascript calling a function from another javascript file

Tags: javascript

File 1

```
var M = function (speech) {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("speech").innerHTML = speech.toString();
};
```

File 2

```
$("#test").click(function () {
  M("hello");
});
```

JS lint probelms v
http://puu.sh/j8AOo/a24a88825b.png

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: Are you meaning to ask how/if it is possible to use two JS libraries and call one from the other? If so, you will need to include a reference for the seond JS file in the first and/or have a reference to the other in both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file)

Answer (score 1):

> 'M' was used before it was defined.

This error is because you're defining `M` as a global variable in one file, and attempting to invoke it in another. Because global variables are often a sign of code-smell, JSLint makes you specifically declare them.  There are a few options to do this. For one, you could prepend `File 2` with `/*global M*/`, and it should stop complaining.

> Missing 'new'.

This is based on variable conventions. In JavaScript, we typically only name constructor functions using CamelCase. Because constructor functions are intended to be called with the `new` keyword, it's detecting this as an error.  In this case, your best option is probably to just rename `M` to `m`.

For more information on configuration and other `JSLint` help topics, see [this page](http://jslint.com/help.html).  Alternatively, if you have any say at all in the matter, I would *strongly* suggest checking out [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) instead.