# How to access function from module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have the following code in `test1.js`.

```
module.exports = function(d){
  d.demo1 = function() {
    return "DEMO 1";
  },

  d.demo2 = function() {
    return "DEMO 2";
  }
}
```

I am trying to access function demo1 on `test2.js`.
Below the code which call the function.

```
var demo = require('./test1');
var result = demo.****;        //code to call function demo1
console.log("calling function", result); //output should be "calling function DEMO 1"
```

Please help how can I access this function.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var demo = require('./test1');
var o = {};
demo(o);
o.demo1(); // "DEMO 1";
```

Answer (score 7):

It is very unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

You're exporting a *function*. That function will take 1 argument (`d`). Then you try to assign the `demo1` and `demo2` properties, of that received argument, to two different functions.

What I *think* you want to do is that you want to export an object with two different properties for those functions. E.g. doing this:

```
module.exports = {
  demo1: function() {
    return "DEMO 1";
  },

  demo2: function() {
    return "DEMO 2";
  }
}
```

Then you can import the module and access the `demo1` and `demo2` functions as:

```
var demo = require('./test1');
var result = demo.demo1();
```

Comment: I know this, but i am trying this in different way which i ask you. Thanx i got solution from #user1280859