# execute function from .js with J2V8

Tags: javascript, android, j2v8

I am using J2V8 for execute JavaScript code on Android. In my Java code, can I access and execute JavaScript functions of a separate .js file? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: How did you install J2V8 in your android project ?

Comment: J2V8 is available in Maven Central. The most recent version is 2.2.1. It can be used in your pom.xml to depend on J2V8. Tutorial: https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/getting-started-with-j2v8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like with many JavaScript environments, you simply *load* the script that contains the other functions you wish to execute [browser example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file). Any functions that are added to the global scope, are now available to you:

`V8 v8 = V8.createV8Runtime();
v8.executeScript(readFileAsString("script1")); // contains the function foo();
v8.executeScript(readFileAsString("script2")); // contains the function bar(x, y);
v8.executeJSFunction("foo");
v8.executeJSFunction("bar", 7, 8);`

Comment: thank you for your answer. can i load the script somehow without using WebView? (I am trying to avoid using WebView at all)

Comment: Yes, there is no webview here at all. I was just showing that with J2V8 it's similar to how a browser works.

Comment: 1. if my function returns an Object, can I get it like this? JSObject testObject = v8.executeJSFunction("testfunction", alfa, beta);

2. once these functions added to the global scope, can i use them in my script? i mean like this:  runtime.executeVoidScript("var testObject =testfunction(alfa, beta) ");

Comment: Yes, it will return a V8Object. You need to call `release()` on this object since it holds a native handle. Re: #2, yes, you can call these in your script just like you did.

Comment: very minor typo in second comment? should that say "contains the function bar(x,y)"?

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Fixed it. I move back and forth between foo / bar and simple math examples too often :)

Comment: Im having issues finding how to install J2V8 in my android project. Any guidelines please?