# Installing/Using J2V8 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, j2v8

I am new to Android Studio development, as well as gradle and j2v8.
I have a sample Hello World app and want to use j2v8 in it (just for curiosity). I have the following in my application gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.j2v8/j2v8_android
    compile group: 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8', name: 'j2v8_android', version: '3.0.5'
}
```

The last one in there is my attempt at adding j2v8.
Next I tried a sample line from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848274/execute-function-from-js-with-j2v8), so I added the following to my Activity:

```
V8 v8 = V8.createV8Runtime();
```

What I don't understand is what imports I need for that to work. I must be missing one or more steps but had a hard time finding instructions online.

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are asking is 'import com.eclipsesource.v8.V8;' ??

Answer (score 5):

using ***compile group: 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8', name: 'j2v8_android', version: '3.0.5'*** , add import com.eclipsesource.v8.V8 also not work.

change to using ***compile 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8_android:3.0.5@aar'*** works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

1. download 3.0.5 aar file from [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/eclipsesource/j2v8/j2v8_android/3.0.5/j2v8_android-3.0.5.aar)
2. Add as a module via Android studio following [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working)