# Calling an external javascript function from within script tags

Tags: javascript

If I do:

```
<body>
    <script>

       readInData();

    </script>
    script - external.js
</body>
```

readInData() doesn't get called and I get an uncaught reference error. (the external.js functions aren't contained within a self-invoking function). but if I put readInData in a firebase call (below) then it executes.

```
 <body>
     <script>

      db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

                  readInData();
      });

    </script>
    script - external.js
  </body>
```

Is that a scope issue? Thanks

Comment: this code is being executed immediately when the page starts to load and there is nothing on the page yet.  I cant tell from your code if you trying to use any page elements but try puting this in a function that gets called after the page has fully loaded.  jquery = $(document).ready({  do stuff here });

Comment: or just put external.js before your function call. Your second example might be doing what @Kevbo suggested for you.

Comment: or just put the external.js in the `head` where it should be and leave the script tag in the body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we call the function written in one JavaScript in another JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the external.js file first so the invocation in your script tag can access it.

```
<body>
<script src="external.js"></script>
<script>

  db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

              readInData();
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like changing order of scripts will solve your issue. If you are lazy - can put big enough `setTimeout(readInData, 10000)` and check if it's connected with timing.
It does not look like scope issue.